# Compare cron to php date()

Tags: php, date, cron

I have a cron that executes many files every minute. But some of them is not needed to be executed every minute, I generate cron's automatically for each of them.
So, I need to compare a cron e.g.  0 2 * * * to date(), and see if the cron has to be executed now, do something in my code.

Thank you.

Comment: You want to compare PHP's current time to that of crond?  Don't you trust your system clock?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: I think he is saying that he has a single cron job, that starts many processes, but some do not need to be started every time.  So he needs to use `date()` (or presumably any time function) in PHP to determine if a particular process needs to happen on this present run.

Answer (score 1):

You should configure each of the scripts as an separate cronjob.
Run in the cron only code that you want executed for the iteration time of the cron itself.